# How to filter the result that include null value in the query?

Tags: sql, null

Hallo, I have a table which have the following item:

```
CODE UPDATE_DT
---- ---------
APP  08-APR-11
REJ  null
CAN  null
```

If I have to filter it by date, lets say for this month, 1-APR-2011 to 30-APR-2011. The output of the query will be like following:

```
CODE UPDATE_DT
---- ---------
APP  08-APR-11
```

Is it possible for me to select query result that could include null value just like the table locate at the top most of this question?

THanks @!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you require "IS NULL", for example, add this to your filter:

```
OR UPDATE_DT IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT code,
       update_dt
  FROM tableName
 WHERE update_dt BETWEEN <your current filter dates>
    OR update_dt IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

add `OR UPDATE_DT IS NULL` at the end of you where clause

Answer (score 1):

You need to bracket your where statement to apply the OR

WHERE (update_dt between [dates] or update_dt IS NULL)